# Node.js invalid argument - argument must be of type string

Tags: node.js, sql-server, arguments

I want to create a node.js app that will pull data from a database and send it to a Google Chatbot. This is the app that queries my database, I have another file that will send the data to Google Chatbot. However, running the code to get the data gives me an invalid argument error.

What am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5PWc.png)

```
var sql = require('mssql'); 
var DailySummary = require(); 

DailySummary.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'localhost', 
        database: 'SupportCaseMonitor' 
    };

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
        if (err) console.log(err);

        var request = new sql.Request();
    
        request.query('SELECT * FROM Message_DailySummary', function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)

            res.send(recordset);
        
        });
    });
});

var server = DailySummary.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
    
function exitProcess() {
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here:

```js
var DailySummary = require();
```

Likely what you meant to write was instead:

```js
const express = require('express');
const DailySummary = express();
```